# Batch file for detecting Internet connected or not

Tags: networking, internet, batch-file

so this is what ive got so far , cant for the love of god get it to work as it should aka meaning its not really reliable in reconnecting once my internet drops after certain amount of time i set for google.com, maybe someone has something much more sophisticated for this / more reliable, has 2 runs as can be seen>

```
@echo

:Loop

GOTO :pingtest

:pingtest
timeout /t 100
ping -n 400 www.google.com
if errorlevel 1 GOTO :fail
if not errorlevel 1 GOTO :success

:fail
echo Sorry, you have failed the test, Reconnecting to the Internet.
  netsh interface set interface "Internet Source" Disable
  netsh interface set interface "Internet Source" Enable

:success
echo You have passed the test and are Connected to the Internet!

GOTO :pingtest 2

:pingtest 2
timeout /t 100
ping -n 400 www.google.com
if errorlevel 1 GOTO :fail2
if not errorlevel 1 GOTO :success2

:fail2
echo Sorry, you have failed the test, Reconnecting to the Internet.
  netsh interface set interface "Internet Source" Disable
  netsh interface set interface "Internet Source" Enable

:success2
echo You have passed the test and are Connected to the Internet!
GOTO :Loop
```

would appreciate alot and would like to have 2 sets of tests like above example and then loop check, thanks

Comment: Regarding the structure, 2 things: (1) you do not need two "sets of tests." What I see is an endless loop with two *identical tests and no loop exit*. This runs endlessly and obviously can be simplified to one test in an endless loop. (2) GOTO labels are merely bookmarks, they are not functions, and execution continues, so when you "goto :fail" it does {magic} and then *continues execution passed the ":success"* label. In other words "goto fail *does both fail and then success*. You want to make another GOTO to jump over the success block (or back to "loop".

Comment: how would this look ? im abit confused , sorry ....also theres a reason why i need 2 test runs ....since i use different executions tied to separate tests , of course i cant post the full code for that , i exempted that on purpose , i just need this code to be improved and as said i dont get it , maybe a code example would be best ...using my template? appreciated

Comment: but also as said if improvements can be made please do, the more sophisticated the better/reliable

Comment: anyone? would appreciate it for sure, means alot to me

Comment: still would appreciate an improved batch, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this Batch Script to detect if you are connected or not to the internet

With a Bonus get your Extrenal IP : [Check if connected to the internet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/po8ygo/check_if_connected_to_the_internet/)

```
@echo off
Title Checking Internet Connection & Mode 70,4 & color 0B
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM First We Check The Status Of The Internet Connection
Call :Check_Connection
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Main
Title Your Extrenal IP Address
Mode 50,4 & Color 0A
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (
   'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:" ^| findstr /v "208.67.222.222" '
 ) Do ( 
    If "%%A" NEQ "127.0.0.1" (
        set "ExtIP=%%A"
    ) else (
        Color 0C & echo(
        echo              No internet connection !
    )
 )
 echo(
 If defined ExtIP (
    echo       You are connected to the internet !
    echo       Your External IP is : %ExtIP%
 )
 Pause>nul & Exit
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Check_Connection
Title Checking Internet Connection ...
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Mode 50,3 & Color 0B
echo(
echo(  Please Wait... Checking Internet Connection ...
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000>nul
cls
echo(
if [!errorlevel!] EQU [1] (
    Color 0C & set "internet=Not Connected To Internet"
    echo(  Connection Status : !Internet!
    CMD /C %SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe ^
    Skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI
    Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul & Goto Check_Connection
) else (
    Color 0A & set "internet=Connected To Internet"
    echo(    Connection Status : !Internet!
    Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul & Goto Main
)
EndLocal
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks man ill check it out , finally someone actually helpful here

Comment: @Etherpixel56 Hope that will work on your side !

Comment: well i tried it but its not really what i need , what i need is an improved version of my above script BUT keeping its layout aka the 2 rounds setup , i need it to tie different apps to it for execution should for example one round fail aka not connect to internet , was kinda hoping someone might come up with something more reliable , something that dont use ping? im no expert if theres other ways than constant pinging , i use timeout /t 100 as seen above , without it it executes said apps tied to each round too early , aka it dont respect the connection wait time to google.com that much

Comment: but also was hoping there was a way to make it dynamic , say for example, no net ....itll instant execute said apps / commands , the issue here is if i use a smaller timeout for example 20 , itll just autoexecute said commands/apps constantly ....even tho im connected to the net aka it isnt respecting the google.com connection timer

Comment: once again would appreciate some help here , thanks

Comment: anyone? still would appreciate some help here...